# Issue writing varchar(max) Column Types in SQL Serve using Rust odbc_api

Tags: sql-server, rust, odbc

I am reading some data from a sql database using `odbc_api` in Rust that has a mixture of column types. However, I noticed that the fields in the table that have `varchar(max)` fail to return back from the table. I am imagining it is related to the `TextRowSet` string buffer size, but even if I change the value from 4 KiB to a massively higher limit, I still do not receive back the varchar columns. Everything builds without warning or error.

code:

```
use anyhow::Error;
use odbc_api::{buffers::TextRowSet, Cursor, Environment, ResultSetMetadata};
use std::io;

const BATCH_SIZE: usize = 100;
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> 
{   
    // Write sql query to stdout
    let out = io::stdout();
    let mut writer = csv::Writer::from_writer(out);

    // Establish environment
    let environment = Environment::new()?; 
    let connection_string = "
        Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};\
        Server=my_server;\
        db=my_db;\
        trusted_connection=yes;
    ";
    let conn = environment.connect_with_connection_string(connection_string)?;
    
    // Set up query and execute
    let qry = "select top 10 * from my_tbl";
    match conn.execute(&qry, ())
    {
        Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
        Ok(Some(mut cursor)) => {
            // Write column names to stdout
            let headline: Vec<String> = cursor.column_names()?.collect::<Result<_,_>>()?;
            writer.write_record(headline)?;
            
            // Use schema in cursor to initialize a text buffer large enough to hold the largest
            // possible strings for each column to an upper limit of 4Kib.
            let mut buffers = TextRowSet::for_cursor(BATCH_SIZE, &mut cursor, Some(4096))?;

            // Bind the buffer to the cursor. It will now be filled with every call to fetch.
            let mut row_set_cursor = cursor.bind_buffer(&mut buffers)?;

            // Iterate over batches
            while let Some(batch) = row_set_cursor.fetch()?
            {   
                // Within a batch, iterate over every row
                for row_index in 0..batch.num_rows()
                {
                    //println!("{}", row_index);
                    let record = (0..batch.num_cols()).map(|col_index| {
                        batch.at(col_index, row_index)
                             .unwrap()
                    });
                    // Writes row as csv
                    writer.write_record(record)?;
                }
            }
        },
        Ok(None) => {
            eprintln!("Query came back empty. No output created.");
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

odbc_api docs: https://docs.rs/odbc-api/latest/odbc_api/

**Hacky Solution EDIT: **

So by going to the source tables and modifying the fields that were `varchar(max)` to `varchar(255)`, I effectively solved the problem. Can anyone explain what happened here?

Comment: Addendum to the answer: The solution to sanatize the database schema is not hacky in my opinion, if you know based on your usecase that the values are actually less in size than 256, it is precisly the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server is reporting an element size of `0` for columns of type `VARCHAR(max)`. Dutifully the text buffer allocates just enough memory for the terminating zero per field, while staying well under the specified upper bound. Since I am the author of `odbc-api` I fixed it in version `0.50.2` which I released after reading your question.

Comment: Thanks for adding this detail and fixing the crate. :)